# How can I get Access to list available values in column filters when using a non-Access backend?

Tags: ms-access

I'm using MS-Access (365) as a frontend to a Postgres table backend.  Communications mech between them is ODBC.  That seems to work fine.

Before I migrated away from the MA-Access backend, a list of check-able options would appear in a column's filter options when filtering column data.  For example, when you clicked on the little carat next to the column name/header, you would see the "Sort A to Z" and "Sort Z to A" (as before) then for the filtering, you would see "Text Filters" as before (with options for specifying the filtering), but then you would also see the options, including "Select All" (a toggle) and then each value with a checkable box next to it.  The user could select/deselect to filter based on the values.  But I no longer see that list of checkable values in the filtering.

The column values are constrained to values in a different table which contains the valid values for that column (a traditional primary/foreign key relationship) and that works fine in the pulldown as a means for a user to pick one of the valid values when editing a record/column.

Since the values of the column are constrained in a predictable, or at least queryable way, I would think that there might be a way to use that to restore those checkable boxes in the filtering.  I looked at the "Design View" of the table and tried a few things to see if I could get this to work. No luck.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this setting:

File->options->Current Database-> Filter lookup options.

[image]

the real problem here is that you really should not be loading up forms with SO MANY records in the first place. But you can try the above settings - and of course increase the 1000 rows. But this is going to cause a performance issues, since this suggests that forms and view are loading large recordsets and THEN you are applying filters to that data. So keep this pulling of data in mind. It is preferable to provide some kind of search form, and let the user search BEFORE you pulled large amounts of data.

So all in all this is a less then ideal option from a performance point of view. But if data pulls are not too large, then this certainly is a "nice" feature - just not a great from a performance point of view.

Comment: Perfect !
Thanks Albert

Comment: Well, with a up-vote and your kindness? I have re-edited the post about "bad" idea to pull too much data to a more kind suggestion that you want to keep a eye on the performance issues here in mind.